# What are some great resources or books for learning about running a website?

Tags: learning, education, books, skills

You've just inherited the webmaster position but know little about the day-to-day operation of a website.  What books or online resources should you look at to learn more about being a webmaster?

Answer (score 2):

Online resources

- This site, obviously
- [Stackoverflow.com](http://stackoverflow.com)
- [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/)

Books

- Read [Code Complete](http://cc2e.com/) (for general coding knowledge, not specific to web dev)

Comment: I've heard good things about Code Complete but not read it myself.

Answer (score 1):

**Here's my hitlist...**

- [sitepoint.com](http://www.sitepoint.com/)
- [alistapart.com](http://www.alistapart.com/)
- [This Site](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/)
- [w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/)
- [htmldog.com](http://www.htmldog.com/)

Sitepoint is probably the closest online resource to what you're looking for.

AListApart is geared more toward style and best practices but it also has a lot of articles about general website management, bleeding edge web technologies, and how to prepare for them.

This site... Obligatory.

The last two aren't specifically geared toward webmasters but, if your webmaster position has anything to do with writing/modifying code on the site you'll wish you had them.

Answer (score 0):

I like O'Reilly Books very much so I'll recomend:

- [Apache Cookbook](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596529949/)
- [Apache Security](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596007249/)
- Some more generic reference book such as [The Definitive Guide](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596002039/) or [Pocket Reference](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596518899/)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot go wrong with O'Reilly's books, especially

- [Webmaster in Nutshell](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596003579/)
- Whole pile of their [webdev selection](http://oreilly.com/pub/topic/webdev/) (but not all at one go ;) )
- For apache the [documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/) as with any webserver.

And one of the best ways is to really run a webserver, you'll learn while experimenting with it.

Comment: I agree on the O'Reilly books. Also depends on what roles your company defines for "Webmaster". Is it maintaining the content of a site? Building new functionality in the site? Maintaining the servers? Databases? etc. etc. If all of the above, you'll be stuck learning (D/X)HTML, CSS, possibly a scripting language like PHP/ASP/ColdFusion, maybe MySQL/MS SQL Server on the database side, Apache/IIS on the server, etc. Each of these disciplines has a wealth of info available, and O'Reilly's tends to cover them all.

Answer (score 0):

[Six Revisions](http://sixrevisions.com/)

While technically a site for Web Devs & Designers they keep things at a high level making for a very good resource for keeping up with technology trends and style.